# Chemical Potentials, why is there N∂µ but no µ∂N?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-potential

I've been studying up on the thermodynamic potentials and I noticed that the four thermo potentials are combinations of the (T,S) and (p,V) pairs. Adding chemical potential adds a (µ,N) pair in the form +µ∂N, but shouldn't there be four more potentials that have a -N∂µ term instead?

Comment: As a matter of application there is nothing stopping you from defining such potentials, and many authors do. They just don't have names fixed by historical usage as do the enthalpy or the Gibbs or Helmholtz free energies. Why *that* is would, perhaps, be better asked on [hsm.se].

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a microcanonical ensemble, i.e. a completely isolated one, we will find that the internal energy is minimized. This internal energy depends solely on extrinsic variables (i.e. properties that grow when we make the system bigger) like particle number, volume, entropy, etc. However, it is often more desirable to control intrinsic variables (i.e. properties independent of the system size) like chemical potential, pressure, temperature, etc. To get to this point mathematically, we make a Legendre transformation. First, look at the total differential of the internal energy $U$:

$$ U=U(N,V,S,\ldots)\\
dU=\mu dN - p dV + T dS+\dots$$

The sign of $pV$ is due to the way we define mechanical​ work performed on and by the system. To "trade" the extrinsic variable $S$ for the intrinsic variable $T$, we define a new potential like so
$$G = U -TS$$ and look at its total derivative $$dG = dU - T dS - S dT = \mu dN - p dV - S dT+\dots$$ in which we see, that it does in fact not depend on $S$, but on $T$. This means that when we keep not $S$, but $T$ constant, the system will go to a state that minimizes $G$. And depending on which variables we "exchange" for their intrinsic partner, these potentials have different names.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question of why there are no name thermodynamic potentials that trade the chemical potential for the particle number.

Comment: The question says nothing about names, only why they are "not there". The answer clearly states that any of these can be constructed and in which cases they would be applicable.